# iphone zxing libZXingWidget.a error

Tags: iphone, xcode

Im installing the ZXing for a QR project,

I have followed the [Readme](http://zxing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/iphone/README) and other [notes](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=622)

but i get an error for not having the libZXingWidget.a

> it appears red always,

in the notes mentioned above, it recomends to change the header search paths to

> "zxing/iphone/ZXingWidget/Classes" directory

but that doesnt work either, so is that the problem?, how to point to the right path?

or how to fix it?,

I import the reference project with no problem, and then when select the libZXingWidget.a , in add frameWork, WorkSpace, the libZXingWidget.a appears in black to be selected, but when selected it goes red,

I imported to the target dependencies  (as recommended in the notes link) the libZXingWidget.a and it continues black,

[image]

this is the error>>

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/tkt/Documents/development/joelind-zxing- iphone-a4159ad/iphone/ZXingWidget/../../cpp/core/src/zxing/common/LocalBlockBinarizer.cpp'
  clang: error: no input files
  Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Red color indicates missing file or directory.Make sure you click the checkbox "recursive path" !

Comment: Checking "recursive path" is not the problem and not a good idea. The zxing headers are not designed to be included recursively.

Comment: In my experience, the color of the link in Xcode can be a bit strange.  Are you getting an error when you build your project, about a missing library?

Comment: hi thanks, i have added the error wich i supposesed was about the missing library, ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just in case other noob, like me gets stucked:

do an  [svn check out for the latest build](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/checkout) !!,

it works straight away!
;)